# The .hhz extension is added to all the files on my computer

Tags: windows

good morning everyone, something unexpected happened to me when I was planning to install software on my computer and suddenly I saw that all my files were left with a .hhz extension, structure as they were named "File.jpg.hhz" I would like to know how I can resolve this conflict and recover my files again since I tried to delete the .hhz extension "File.jpg" but the file no longer opens so I decided to leave them with the .hhz extension but I don't know how to recover these files....

I thank you in advance for all the collaboration you can provide me to resolve this conflict.

It should be noted that it was portable software that I needed to get through a task and I thought it was legitimate.